# Using colcon, is there a way to skip a "top" CMakeLists.txt and detect packages in sub-folders?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following file structure with a mix of legacy code and some ROS packages in a single git repository:

```
src/top_project/CMakeLists.txt
src/top_project/sub_project1/CMakeLists.txt # no ROS
src/top_project/sub_project2/CMakeLists.txt # with ROS
src/top_project/sub_project2/package.xml
```

The `top_project/CMakeLists.txt` is provided for non ROS users and is just a list of `add_subdirectory(sub_projectN)`.  I would like colcon to ignore the `top_project/CMakeLists.txt` and potentially treat each `sub_project` as a separate package.  I tried adding `COLCON_IGNORE` but this lead to the whole directory and subdirectories being ignored.   Is there something like `COLCON_IGNORE_CWD` to ignore `top_project` but recursively search the sub folders?    To note, I'm trying to port ROS1 libraries build with python catkin build tools which relied on the fact that directories without `package.xml` where ignored and we had to explicitly provide a `package.xml` for each actual package.

I'm using ROS 2 Eloquent with:

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"

> colcon version-check 
colcon-argcomplete 0.3.3: up-to-date
colcon-bash 0.4.2: up-to-date
colcon-cd 0.1.1: up-to-date
colcon-cmake 0.2.18: up-to-date
colcon-core 0.5.3: up-to-date
colcon-defaults 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-devtools 0.2.2: up-to-date
colcon-library-path 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-metadata 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-notification 0.2.12: up-to-date
colcon-output 0.2.7: up-to-date
colcon-package-information 0.3.1: up-to-date
colcon-package-selection 0.2.5: up-to-date
colcon-parallel-executor 0.2.4: up-to-date
colcon-pkg-config 0.1.0: up-to-date
colcon-powershell 0.3.6: up-to-date
colcon-python-setup-py 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-recursive-crawl 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-ros 0.3.15: up-to-date
colcon-test-result 0.3.8: up-to-date
colcon-zsh 0.4.0: up-to-date
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345068/using-colcon,-is-there-a-way-to-skip-a-%22top%22-cmakelists.txt-and-detect-packages-in-sub-folders?/) by [anton.deguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/52067/anton.deguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no option to ignore that specific file.

As a workaround - instead of using the default (recursively crawling for packages which stops at that CMake file) - you can choose a different way to discover packages:

- If all packages are direct subdirectories of `src` you could call `colcon` with `--paths src/*`.
- If you need crawl recursively under `src` you can pass `--base-paths src/*`.

Both options are described when you invoke e.g. `colcon build --help`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2